# Why doesn't my function override the Alt+D keydown event in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I am unable to override the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keydown event in Microsoft Edge using JavaScript; it works for all other browsers, though. It's navigating to the address bar.

Here's my on keydown event

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) { 
    if (e.altKey && e.key == "d") { 
        e.cancelBubble = true; 
        e.returnValue = false; 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        alert(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I try to test the issue and I am able to produce the issue. In my test, I notice that Edge browser is only identifying the ALT key. https://i.postimg.cc/Wb05VVkx/322.png I also noticed that other user had already posted the issue for this. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/23346355/ I suggest you to submit your feedback on that issue. I tried various workarounds but it did not worked. I will make further research and let you know about any work around for this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you , If you found any solution Please let me know @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: I will inform you.

Answer (score 0):

We had again tested the issue and we found that it is happened due to conflict.

As you know, Alt + D key is a short cut key for selecting the address bar in MS Edge browser.

So it always executes instead of your code.

As we cannot change this shortcut key, if it is possible for you then you can try to use any other letter instead of D in a combination.

For example, here in a test I am using E letter. This can be the work around for this issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).keydown(function (e) { 
   
    if (e.altKey && e.key == "e") { 
        e.cancelBubble = true; 
        e.returnValue = false; 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        alert("hello..."); 
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a test. Press Alt + e</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]